# Exclude css form specific element from specific file.css

Tags: css

Similar questions has been asked but this is more specific.
I have page which is created by user through form (shopware). From some reason  element do not have padding given trough form. It get's css rules from some other css file which works globally. If in inspect i remove that rules I get padding given through form by user.

**Is there a way to exclude rules from specific css file**, override it or whatever but to keep those given by user?

Comment: put it inline and make sure the important tag is not used in the other style sheet or make sure the user input styleS are included after the other stylesheet and are more specific than the other style sheet.  But without seeing any code / examples of what is causing the issue, this question is off topic for so

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, some of the least dirty:

1. Add specific class for your block and put you new styles here.
2. Make the path to element more "weighted" with your form

For example:

```
/* global path in css: */
.wrapper form .inner_block { ... }
/* you form has also some class .my_class */
.wrapper form .inner_block.my_class { ... }
/* or add extra element, if it is different from global: */
.wrapper form div.inner_block { ... }
```

3. Do not include css file at all in your template in this page (it will be probably not your case).
4. Write inline-style, but this is the worst solution.